# Allow Editing Short Name for Dexterity Add/Edit Form

Tags: plone, dexterity

I want some custom Dexterity types can be explicitly edited for their short name (ID, that will be part of the URL) field. If the short name field is left blank, then it will be calculated from the (required) title field value by the enabled `plone.app.content.interfacess.INameFromTitle` behavior.

By default, I see no short name field when adding/editing the type. Only via `object_rename` from action menu I can set its short name. What is the best practice for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` field is not part of the Dexterity schema, *at all*.

You'd have to create an additional behaviour that adds it.

Comment: Thanks. And I find a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077886/how-can-i-change-the-url-of-an-object-serverd-by-dexterity-in-plone

Comment: For the record. Specifically I need NameFromCreationDate behavior, and here is how I work out: http://marrtw.blogspot.tw/2013/07/name-from-creation-date-behavior.html